# Better choice: TextLayout or JTextComponent for an "ellipse with editable text" component?

Tags: swing, jtextcomponent

If you've ever used Visio or a UML class diagram editor, you have an idea of what I'm trying to accomplish: Within a JFrame, users can add ellipses that enclose a small editable text field. These ellipses can be repositioned within the frame when the user drags them. Clicking on an ellipse causes the text to become editable: a carat appears, highlighting a substring is possible, etc.

I've got the basic structure set up: the 'ellipse' is a self-contained component, with methods called on it from the containing JFrame and its listeners. I've tried two approaches:

1. in the component's draw() method, use a TextLayout to find bounds, position the contained text within the ellipse, and draw it to the frame using TextLayout's draw(). This is fast. Dragging the components around in the JFrame, mouse-over and mouse-click behavior are all straightforward. However for the editing functionality it looks like I will need to write a lot of custom code to handle hit testing, carat positioning, text highlighting, line wrapping, etc.
2. having the component contain a reference to the containing JFrame, and adding or repositioning a TextComponent in that JFrame after drawing the ellipse. This has the advantage of all the built-in TextComponent behavior for editing and line wrapping. But the logistics are really sloppy, and positioning the TextComponent becomes messy too - especially when the user drags the component around.

I'm quite possibly thinking about this all wrong. Can anyone suggest a simple way to do this that I haven't yet stumbled across?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you combine both your approaches. As long as you are editing, display the text component, otherwise paint all text using a `TextLayout`. The following example code shows such an approach extending a simple `JComponent`. It draws a rectangular shape with some text in it and if you click inside it shows an editing possibility. As soon as you click outside again, the component vanished. Note that all the edit-handling functionality is missing in this basic example.

```
class TestComponent extends JComponent {
    JTextArea jta = new JTextArea("12345");

    public TestComponent() {
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 400));
        setLayout(null);
        addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(final MouseEvent e) {
                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        if (e.getX() >= 40 && e.getX() <= 200 && e.getY() >= 40 && e.getY() <= 80) {
                            TestComponent.this.add(jta);
                            jta.setBounds(42, 42, 156, 36);
                        } else {
                            TestComponent.this.remove(jta);
                        }
                        repaint();
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics _g) {
        Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) _g;
        g.drawRect(40, 40, 160, 40);
        TextLayout layout = new TextLayout("12345", g.getFont(), g.getFontRenderContext());
        layout.draw(g, 42, 42 + layout.getAscent());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thx Howard, I'll try this approach!